# I'm getting error while running application in my local host.XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax

i want to test my page from local host which contains get api which is hoster in remote server. while im executing this page im getting this error in console.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abcsoftwares.in/mymethod/get. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:6366' is therefore not allowed access.
im using ajax calls here to get json resonse.

```
    function LoadChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://abcsoftwares.in/mymethod/get',
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    var WaterTemperature = 12;                       
                    var fusioncharts = new FusionCharts({
                        type: 'thermometer',
                        renderAt: 'abcdef',
                        id: 'myThm',
                        width: '240',
                        height: '301',
                        dataFormat: 'json',
                        dataSource: {
                            "chart": {

                            },
                            "value": abc,
                            "annotations": {
                                "showbelow": "0",
                                "groups": [{
                                    "id": "indicator",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "background",
                                            "type": "rectangle",

                                        }
                                    ]
                                }]

                            },
                        }
                    });
```

i don't want to change url for testing in local host.

Answer (score 0):

As the given error message said:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:6366' is therefore not allowed access.

You cannot GET or POST to remote that not allow you to access.
One common solution is to add a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to the API server.

Answer (score 0):

Your server app must enable CORS

In your WebApiConfig:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

In each action decorate with this:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```